# Can HAARP warp space-time?

Tags: physics, electromagnetism, haarp

According to [this article](http://beforeitsnews.com/science-and-technology/2012/05/physicist-haarp-manipulates-time-2167703.html)

> A brilliant physicist published a [revolutionary paper citing 30 other scientific papers](http://vixra.org/pdf/1202.0044v1.pdf) that reveal [HAARP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Frequency_Active_Auroral_Research_Program) has incredible powers far beyond what most investigators of the high frequency energy technology suspect.
>
> **Dr. Fran De Aquino asserts a fully functional HAARP network, activated globally, can not only affect weather and geophysical events, but influence space and gravity…even time itself!**
>
> Now the network is almost complete with the activation of the newest HAARP facilities at the bottom of the world: the desolate and alien Antarctic.

Can HAARP influence space, gravity and time as suggested by the article?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **Can HAARP influence space, gravity and time as suggested by the article?**

According to the paper cited, *"High-power ELF radiation generated by modulated HF heating of the ionosphere can cause Earthquakes, Cyclones and localized heating"*, HAARP's power is 3.6 x 10^9 W

According to [HAARP](http://www.universetoday.com/73693/what-is-solar-energy/#gsc.tab=0) the actual power is 1000 times smaller than this - 3.6 x 10^6 W.

The Sun radiates 174 x 10^15 W onto the planet. Of this 35 x 10^15 W is absorbed by the atmosphere. [Ref](http://www.universetoday.com/73693/what-is-solar-energy/#gsc.tab=0)

So the Sun's radiation absorbed in the atmosphere is 10^9 times larger than HAARP, of course it is also over a much larger volume, so this needs to be taken into account ...

According to [HAARP](http://www.haarp.alaska.edu/haarp/tech.html)

> The intensity of the HF signal in the ionosphere is less than 3 microwatts per cm2, tens of thousands of times less than the Sun's natural electromagnetic radiation reaching the earth and hundreds of times less than even the normal random variations in intensity of the Sun's natural ultraviolet (UV) energy which creates the ionosphere.

This is consistent with the known facts.

It therefore seems unlikely that HAARP has sufficient energy to cause significant earthquakes or cyclones. Nor to influence space, gravity or time in any novel or unusual ways.

Dr. Fran De Aquino's paper goes on to discuss his theory of gravitational shielding whereby a couple of people can render heavy rock monoliths weightless by draping them with a "gravitational shielding mantle" that multiplies the Sun's gravity. In my view, this confusion of topics rather undermines the credibility of the article.

Whatever harmful effects HAARP may be capable of, this paper does not seem a credible account of them.

Comment: "It therefore seems unlikely that HAARP has insufficient energy to cause significant earthquakes" - too many negatives :) Are you saying it is likely HAARP has sufficient energy to cause significant earthquakes?

Comment: The total energy of HAARP is indeed quite small compared with it of Sun. However, there is two point should be noticed. The first one is the EM-wave emitted by Sun is broad-spectrum whereas it is much narrower of HAARP(so the energy density may not so smaller than it of Sun). What's more if the frequency of EM-waves emitted by HAARP is similar with the natural frequency of something(maybe gravitational shielding mantle), it is possibly to cause resonance even with a small total energy. These two seems notable.

Comment: So what you are really saying is that you do not know but it defies logic to your mind?  That doesnt really make a good skeptics answer.